# Fetch data from database in angularjs to form

Tags: angularjs

In front page there are two options:

1.create new

2.edit

1.it goes to index.html

2.it should be goes to index html with data(data should be load from database)

//get data from database

```
$scope.getItem = function(id) {
               var auth = btoa("root:root");
               $scope.form["@class"] = "ProjectDetails";
               $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + auth;
               $http.get("http://azuspeedcp01:2480/document/InternalRPA/"+id+"/*:-1", {


                   })
                   .then(function(response) {

                   console.log(response);
                   $scope.form=response.data; 

                   });       

  }
```

here i retrieve data from db is fine.its **response.data**
again assign to $scope.form which is the object i passed from form to submit data.

//index.html(partial)

```
<input type="text" id="clientName" ng-model="form.ClientName">
<input type="text" id="initiate" ng-model="form.City">
<select id="Geo" ng-model="form.Geo">
    <option value="North America">North America</option>
</select>
```

How to route to index.html with data. I don't have idea.please help me.

Comment: What is the content of `response.data`?

Comment: Show the full code

Comment: @sisyphus response.data means it gives json from db with whole data that i need to set in form

Comment: @Manikandan its big coding. i couldnt be able to post here or set in js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

- it goes to **index.html**
- it should be goes to **index html** with data(data should be load from database)

> So you want always staying in the same screen, then why you want to redirect(refresh) on the same screen? **You can use the same scope object anywhere in the same screen(index.html)**,

---

- it should be goes to **index html** with data(data should be load from database)

> If you want to redirect with data. then Just use `location.$path("routename")` to redirect the screen and maintain the values by using `$localStorage`

Comment: i didn't get it what you said.same form but in second option i need data which are in db

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that I can use angular service to route from one service to another.Thanks all to help me

```
   app.service('srvShareData', function($window) {
    var KEY = 'App.SelectedValue';

    var addData = function(newObj) {
        alert("2"+newObj);



   $window.sessionStorage.setItem(KEY,JSON.stringify(newObj));

    };

    var getData = function(){
        var mydata = $window.sessionStorage.getItem(KEY);


    return mydata;
    };
    return {

        addData: addData,
        getData: getData
    };
})
```